# Saving UnknownFields to a map while deserializing Json using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

My class looks like:

```
Class A{
    private String amount;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String,String> unknownFields = new HashMap<>();

}
```

My `ObjectMapper` have `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES = false` configured.

```
Json input:
{
   "amount": 5000,
   "note" : "Amount is 5000"
}
```

In this case I need the note to be in the `unknownFields` Map:

I am looking for some annotations like

```
@OnUnknownProperties
public void OnUnknownProperties(String name, String value){
    unknownFields.put(name,value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ecbrodie for formatting and making spelling corrections. Next time onwards, I will ensure it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could annotate a Method in your Domain-Class with @JsonAnySetter (@JsonAnyGetter) and handle it. A good example is here:
http://www.jasonwhaley.com/handling-top-level-metadata-with-jackson/ . Let your DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=false.